# How many times $f-g$ changes sign in $(0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis

Consider $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$

Question: How many times $f-g$ changes sign in $(0,\infty)$

Let us call $h=f-g$

Note that $e^{x^2}=1+x^2+x^4/2!+\dots \geq 1+x^2$

so $e^{-x^2}<\frac{1}{1+x^2}$

We conclude that $f-g<0$ so there is no sign change? Right

Thanks.

Comment: That is correct - there is no sign change.

Comment: How does $\ge$ become a strict $<$ when you take reciprocals?